# Celery and Django - Running worker as Daemon (Mac OS X)

Tags: django, celery, daemon, django-celery

I have a Django project in Mac OS X (10.8.4) with an application that intends to model an airport.  In the database, SQLite, I have several tables and one of them is for flight delays (flight, date, new_hour, cause).

My objective is to use Celery to perform certain tasks like notify users for delays on their flights and delete delays which are no longer valid.  For this, I thought that I would run the Celery worker as a daemon but I have encountered huge problems when trying to read the documentation on how to do this.

So I have followed the instructions on how to configure my Django project to use Celery, defining and calling tasks, starting the worker process and calling the task.  I have an extra application on my project called celerytest and a tasks.py file that looks like this:

```
from celery import task
from flughafen.models import Country, Airline, Aircraft, Airport, Flight, Reservation, CheckIn, Delay

@task()
def delete_delays():
    # code to retrieve delays which are no longer valid and to delete them
```

I can call this task based on the instructions given [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#starting-the-worker-process).  However, when I read the instructions for [Running the worker as a daemon](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html#daemonizing) it is not clear for me what to do.

The documentation mentions a link for Mac OS X which redirects me to a github page where there are some plist files which I am supposed to load with launchctl.  I have downloaded them and loaded them, but they appear with an exit status:

```
octavio:daemon ohd$ launchctl load org.celeryq.celerybeat.plist
octavio:daemon ohd$ launchctl load org.celeryq.celeryd.plist
octavio:daemon ohd$ launchctl load org.celeryq.celerymon.plist
octavio:daemon ohd$ launchctl list | grep celery
-   2   org.celeryq.celerymon
-   2   org.celeryq.celeryd
-   2   org.celeryq.celerybeat
```

I guess I am missing some configuration like [this](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html#example-django-configuration) or [this](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html#generic-initd-celerybeat-django-example), but I am not sure where should it be located.

Could anyone please provide me with advise?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was struggling with the issue.  While I didn't go the launchd route, I eventually got daemonized workers using the daemonize utility.

http://software.clapper.org/daemonize/

You can easily install it with brew.

Then using Fabric I can restart the workers like so:

```
def celeryd():
    with cd('/usr/local/Cellar/daemonize/1.7.4/sbin'):
        # Kill existing workers
        sudo('ps auxww | grep celeryd | grep -v "grep" | awk \'{print $2}\' | xargs kill')
        # Create new workers
        sudo('daemonize -u pipeadmin %s/manage.py celery worker' % siteDir)
```